# Don't use WPF ContentMenu For Grid With Caliburn Micro

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a Grid on WPF with 5 columns: ID , Name, Address, Salary, Phone. And Now i want to click Right Mouse to a row on grid. My main idea is I get ID on rows when i right click into "Detail" menu.
My result is i don't get ID.

My Code is :

```
<DataGrid>
     <DataGrid.ContentMenu>
       <ContentMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
         <MenuItem Header="Detail" cal:Message.Attach="Detail($dataContext)">
         </MenuItem>
      </ContentMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContentMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I don't undertand. Would you clarify " Where are you supposed to see the Id?"

Comment: Like as my posts , My question. How to get value on row by WPF ContentMenu event with caliburn micro ?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Converter` to check your `DataContext` is correct?

Comment: I just want to get data of row which i click right into. Can you help me ?

Comment: That's why I asked about converter. `DataTemplate` is not part of the visual tree until `RunTime`. So you will only have access to it when the app runs.

Answer (score 0):

CM has and will always have a visual tree issue, meaning it can't map the ContextMenu until its in the visual tree...

So there exists `Action.TargetWithoutContext`

["No target found for method" thrown by Caliburn Message.Attach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587368/no-target-found-for-method-thrown-by-caliburn-message-attach)